# How to move a div below another on different screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am trying to get this moved below however I am not getting the right results. This is on a CMS based website, so I seem to only get access to the CSS.

[image]

```
@media (max-width: 762px){
  .listing-item__logo{
     float: right;
     display: inherit !important;
     vertical-align: text-bottom !important;
     width: 50% !important;
  }
}
```

by default this logo isn't displayed below 762px, so I had alter that by the display. But now I would like to get that side beside the text and the text move to the left, to allow for space. As for one, when this is in mobile view, the title gets completely squashed.

I'm more than likely being thick as anything but shall see.

```css
@media (max-width: 762px){
.listing-item__logo{
  float: right;
  display: inherit !important;
  vertical-align: text-bottom !important;
  width: 50% !important;
}
}

/***MY CODE ^^****/

/***ORIGINAL**/

.listing-item__logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; }
  @media all and (max-width: 992px) {
    .listing-item__logo {
      min-width: 170px;
      width: 170px; } }
  .listing-item__logo.listing-item__resumes {
    min-width: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    padding-right: 21px; }
  @media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    .listing-item__logo {
      display: none; } }
  .listing-item__logo .media-object:not(.profile__img) {
    max-width: 125px;
    max-height: 125px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<article class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs  ">
  <div class="media-left listing-item__logo">
    <a href="https://energymaniacs.net/job/73250/planner/">
      <img class="media-object profile__img-company" src="https://energymaniacs.net/files/pictures/orion_1.png" alt="Orion Group">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="media-heading listing-item__title">
    <a href="https://energymaniacs.net/job/73250/planner/" class="link">Planner</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing-item__info clearfix">
    <span class="listing-item__info--item listing-item__info--item-company">
    Orion Group
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="listing-item__desc hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    Our client is currently recruiting for the position of a Planner based in Aberdeen, Aberdeen-Shire.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="media-right text-right">
    <div class="listing-item__date">
    Mar 02, 2017
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item__desc visible-sm visible-xs">
  Our client is currently recruiting for the position of a Planner based in Aberdeen, Aberdeen-Shire.
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code Updated**

Will something like this work?

```css
@media (max-width: 762px){
.listing-item__logo{
  float: right;
  display: inherit !important;
  vertical-align: text-bottom !important;
  width: 50% !important;
}

.listing-item .media-body, .listing-item__desc, .listing-item__info--item-company, .media-right {
float: left;
max-width: 50%;
clear: left;
}

/***MY CODE ^^****/

/***ORIGINAL**/

.listing-item__logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-width: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; }
  @media all and (max-width: 992px) {
    .listing-item__logo {
      min-width: 170px;
      width: 170px; } }
  .listing-item__logo.listing-item__resumes {
    min-width: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    padding-right: 21px; }
  @media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    .listing-item__logo {
      display: none; } }
  .listing-item__logo .media-object:not(.profile__img) {
    max-width: 125px;
    max-height: 125px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<article class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs  ">
  <div class="media-left listing-item__logo">
    <a href="https://energymaniacs.net/job/73250/planner/">
      <img class="media-object profile__img-company" src="https://energymaniacs.net/files/pictures/orion_1.png" alt="Orion Group">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="media-heading listing-item__title">
    <a href="https://energymaniacs.net/job/73250/planner/" class="link">Planner</a>
    </div>
    <div class="listing-item__info clearfix">
    <span class="listing-item__info--item listing-item__info--item-company">
    Orion Group
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="listing-item__desc hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    Our client is currently recruiting for the position of a Planner based in Aberdeen, Aberdeen-Shire.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="media-right text-right">
    <div class="listing-item__date">
    Mar 02, 2017
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="listing-item__desc visible-sm visible-xs">
  Our client is currently recruiting for the position of a Planner based in Aberdeen, Aberdeen-Shire.
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: No quite, but it has done something. Will add link - https://gallery.fs-uk.com/120039_03_03_17_1_03_17.png

Comment: @TaylorGathercole, i have updated the code. You can play with the max-width and width of logo to have a better effect as per your requirements.

Comment: Fact only other thing I would say is, how would I go about getting that text to go the entire way across? Instead of squashed as well? link - https://gallery.fs-uk.com/120039_03_03_17_1_13_45.png

Comment: Or the other way, the logo at the bottom and the title goes the entire way across

Comment: If my answer helped you,  then please select is as the answer so that others can get benefit.  

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `pull` of bootstrap ?
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Hope this help

Comment: Problem with that is I don't have access directly to the html, it's all implemented in php and template files. So I'm trying to do my best by overriding it all